# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException, could not find writer for content-type application/json type, in Payara Server 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, payara, javax.ws.rs.processingexception

first `Sorry for my bulky source code and simple question.`

I get this error.

**javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.acme.customers.lib.v1.Customer**

Complete Trace:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ acme-customers-api ---
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.acme.customers.lib.v1.Customer
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:488)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:65)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:226)
    at com.acme.customers.api.rest.v1.test.ConsumingServices.main(ConsumingServices.java:67)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: com.acme.customers.lib.v1.Customer
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:302)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.syncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:224)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:589)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.buildEntity(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:548)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.loadHttpMethod(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:455)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:265)
    ... 4 more
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  5.277 s
Finished at: 2020-09-03T10:55:26-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project acme-customers-api: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Using Postman with URL **http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers/createPurchaser**

[image]

With the Header
[image]

My `ConsumingServices` class is

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;

public class ConsumingServices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("John");
        customer.setLastName("Mason");
        customer.setEmail("john.mason@mail.com");
        customer.setDateOfBirth(new Date());
        customer.setStatus(CustomerStatus.ACTIVE);

        ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
        configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);

        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers");

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.path("createPurchaser")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Response response = invocationBuilder
                .header("Authorization", "1234")
                .post(Entity.entity(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            Purchaser purchaser = response.readEntity(Purchaser.class);
            System.out.println("purchaser:".concat(purchaser.toString()));
        } else {
            if (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE.equals(response.getMediaType())) {
                String message = response.readEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println("message:" + message);
            } else if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(response.getMediaType())) {
                ApiError apiError = response.readEntity(ApiError.class);
                System.out.println("apiError:".concat(apiError.toString()));
            } else {
                System.out.println("response.getMediaType():" + response.getMediaType());
                String content = response.readEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println("message:" + content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Line with Exception is **`.post(Entity.entity(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`**

My Dependencies in the `pom.xml` are

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-customers-lib</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-embedded-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-web-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**QUESTION: How could I fix this exception?**

The code of my classes....

The `CustomerResource` class

```
@Path("/customers")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/createPurchaser")
    public Response createPurchaser(Customer customer) {
        return Response
            .status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity(customerService.createPurchaser(customer))
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
    }
}
```

The `CustomerService` interface

```
public interface CustomerService {

    Purchaser createPurchaser(Customer customer);
}
```

The `createPurchaser` method of `CustomerServiceImpl` class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Override
    public Purchaser createPurchaser(Customer customer) {

        if (customer == null) {
            throw new EmptyPayloadException(Customer.class.getSimpleName());
        }
        
        Purchaser client = new Purchaser();
        
        client.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
        client.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
        client.setAffiliationDate(new Date());
        client.setCustomerStatus(CustomerStatus.ACTIVE);
        client.setPurchaserDocument(new PurchaserDocument());
        client.getPurchaserDocument().setDateOfBirth(customer.getDateOfBirth());
        client.getPurchaserDocument().setNumberDocument(new Random().nextLong());
        client.getPurchaserDocument().setTypeDocument("CC");
        return client;
    }
}
```

The `Customer` class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer extends BaseType implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private CustomerStatus status;
    private String email;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public CustomerStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(CustomerStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Now the `BaseType` class

```
import java.util.Date;
public class BaseType {

    private String id;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }
    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

the `CustomerStatus` enum

```
public enum CustomerStatus {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE
}
```

The `Purchaser` class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Purchaser implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date affiliationDate;
    private CustomerStatus customerStatus;
    private PurchaserDocument purchaserDocument;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Date getAffiliationDate() {
        return affiliationDate;
    }
    public void setAffiliationDate(Date affiliationDate) {
        this.affiliationDate = affiliationDate;
    }
    public CustomerStatus getCustomerStatus() {
        return customerStatus;
    }
    public void setCustomerStatus(CustomerStatus customerStatus) {
        this.customerStatus = customerStatus;
    }
    public PurchaserDocument getPurchaserDocument() {
        return purchaserDocument;
    }
    public void setPurchaserDocument(PurchaserDocument purchaserDocument) {
        this.purchaserDocument = purchaserDocument;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Purchaser{firstName=").append(firstName);
        sb.append(", lastName=").append(lastName);
        sb.append(", affiliationDate=").append(affiliationDate);
        sb.append(", customerStatus=").append(customerStatus);
        sb.append(", purchaserDocument=").append(purchaserDocument);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The `PurchaserDocument` class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class PurchaserDocument implements Serializable {

    private String typeDocument;
    private Long numberDocument;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public String getTypeDocument() {
        return typeDocument;
    }
    public void setTypeDocument(String typeDocument) {
        this.typeDocument = typeDocument;
    }
    public Long getNumberDocument() {
        return numberDocument;
    }
    public void setNumberDocument(Long numberDocument) {
        this.numberDocument = numberDocument;
    }
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `jersey-client` dependency. You need to remove it. Reason: The generic `ClientBuilder` is [built to *always* become a `JerseyClientBuilder`](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.java#L94) when Jersey client is on the classpath. The JSON dependency you have (that automatically registers with the RESTEast client) `resteasy-jackson2-provider` is for RESTEasy. So Jersey client doesn't recognize it. You could manually register the provider with the client and it should work.

```
client.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
```

But like I said, just remove `jersey-client` and `ClientBuilder` will become `ResteasyClientBuilder` and it will recognize the `resteasy-jackson2-provider` and automatically register it. Unless your goal *is* to use the Jersey client, in which case, you need to manually register the provider, or add the Jersey auto-register dependency, which is `jersey-media-json-jackson`.

#### Update

Note, if you plan on using the client in the server environment, I just noticed that you are using Payara, which uses Jersey under the hood. So the server is already equipped with all the Jersey jars. If you want to use Jackson as your provider, you should add `jersey-media-json-jackson` and register the `JacksonFeature` with the client. If you don't do this, it will default to using JSONB as the JSON provider. If you want to use RESTEasy, then you can forget this.

Comment: Thanks, But according to `ConsumingServices` class (the client class) how must be done the `client.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);`?

Comment: Where do you see `client`?

Comment: If I understanding you, I put the `ConsumingServices` class (the client class)  is outside the project in another maven project.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. In that class you delare `Client client = ClientBuilder...` That is the `client` you need to call `register()` on. Whether or not it's a different project I know nothing about. I'm basing my answer on the dependencies you re showing in your post.